# WinMinimize behavior isn't correct

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I'm using WinMinimize in my script to minimize various windows to the taskbar

The default behavior for minimization is minimize to the taskbar. But some programs are set to minimize to the tray. They minimize to the tray when the minimize button on the program's window is pressed, but when WinMinimize command is used to minimize that program's window it gets minimized to the taskbar instead to the tray.

Any solutions to this problem?

Edit: I'm testing it on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

AHK's `WinMinimize` maps to the WinAPI function to minimize window. It bypasses any custom handling the application might have implemented (e.g. minimize to tray).

To simulate click on the minimize button, one has to send to the window the [`WM_SYSCOMMAND` message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with parameter `SC_MINIMIZE`. (The names of the constants are unknown to AHK: you have to use the numeric values specified in the documentation.)

For example (tested on Win7/x64) to send the minimize message to active window using the Win-H shortcut:

```
#h::PostMessage, 0x112, 0xF020, 0, , A
```

See [PostMessage](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/PostMessage.htm) documentation for more info.

Comment: PostMessage and SendMessage fail on certain windows, but they always signal success. They will succeed if the window should go to tray.

Comment: @this, I have just tested that on Win7/x64 with mIRC (minimize to tray) and lots of other applications - the minimization works reliably for me.